# IllegalArgumentException on parameter convertView at Adapter.getView Kotlin android

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter convertView
Adapter.getView
 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
```

This is logcat of android.
I tried with java it's working fine base adapter something wrong in Adapter or other.
I tried with the `public constructor` and also array list count 3 found i checked it. Alway it's crash at `getView`

MyAdapter Code::

```
   inner class MyAppAdapter constructor(private val parkingList: ArrayList<App>, private val mContext: Context) : BaseAdapter() {

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return this.parkingList.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return position
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
            val viewHolder: ViewHolder
            var rowView: View? = convertView
            if (rowView == null) {
                rowView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_more_apps, parent, false)
                viewHolder = ViewHolder()
                viewHolder.appIcon = rowView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon)
                viewHolder.appName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.appName)
                viewHolder.appDescription = rowView.findViewById(R.id.appDescription)
                rowView.tag = viewHolder
            } else {
                viewHolder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
            }
            viewHolder.appName!!.text = String.format("%s", this.parkingList[position].name)
            viewHolder.appDescription!!.text = String.format("%s", this.parkingList[position].description)
            Glide.with(applicationContext).load(this.parkingList[position].icon).into(viewHolder.appIcon!!)
            rowView?.setOnClickListener {
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this@MyAppAdapter.parkingList[position].link)))
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    startActivity(Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this@MyAppAdapter.parkingList[position].link)))
                }
            }
            return rowView
        }

        inner class ViewHolder {
            var appDescription: TextView? = null
            var appIcon: ImageView? = null
            var appName: TextView? = null
        }
    }
```

Used at `AsyncTask` -> `onPostExecute`

```
  myAppAdapter = MyAppAdapter(appArrayList, applicationContext)
            lvPoses!!.adapter = myAppAdapter
```

Variable Decleared like this

```
   lateinit var myAppAdapter: MyAppAdapter
    private val appArrayList = ArrayList<App>()
    private var lvPoses: ListView? = null
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`convertView` can be null if no view has been created yet. Fix parametr declaration:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: 
     ViewGroup): View? {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 'convertView: View?'

Comment: convertview is updated as non null   `convertView!!`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Asynctasks, not sure if this will help you, but if you just execute the asynctask (without the `.get()` ). Your code after calling asynctask will run, but the element is still NULL as the Asynctask didnt execute yet, and when it did it was already too late. Try adding `.get()` after execute (it will freeze the UI, but the postExecute method will be called in time). Or another approach is to set a boolean variable false and make it true when post executed was executed then check every second or so (Timer, Thread) if the variable is true and then execute the rest of the code. For better UI experience add progressdialog between `preExecute` and `postExecute`.

Or you can also set the view to be NULL but I dont think that fixes your problem as you dont want it to be NULL.